# Aligning in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image][image][image]

How do you equally space these around the center in Illustrator please?

Answer (score 4):

You really can't in any easy, effective, manner. You'd have to measure between each element and use guides and manually position each object...

**It would be quicker and easier to build a circle and the shapes from scratch and then color them as needed.**

1. Draw 2 circles - `Object > Compound Shape > Make`
2. Draw a triangle with the primary point at the center of the circles.
3. `Effect > Distort & Transform & Transform` with the triangle
   selected (note settings in animation below -- I counted your spaces which is why I use "17" in the effect).
4. `Object > Expand Appearance` on triangles
5. `Select All` - > `Pathfinder Panel > Minus Front button`
6. Then color as desired. (May need to ungroup first `Object >
   Ungroup`)

[image]

This way everything is equally spaced and aligned before you add color.

Comment: Clearly I did something wrong because they are not uniform in size. The green is my attempt. It does look much better than my original one.

Comment: I also included my happy accidents. : )

Comment: @ElizabethHart the point of your triangle isn't centered so when you apply the effect, there's a slight skew to the copies. The triangle needs the bottom point to be exactly equidistant from the other two points horizontally.

Comment: Thank you. Scott. I will try another attempt tomorrow when I am more bright-eyed and bushy-tailed. : )

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method using a Pattern Brush.

1. Create a single rectangular shape, fill with green and no stroke,
   then copy and paste in place a second rectangle, with no fill or
   stroke, then extended it a little to make a gap.
2. Select both shapes and make a pattern brush, by clicking the tiny
   menu icon in the Brushes palette, click New Brush, choose "pattern"
   option.
3. Then apply the pattern brush stroke you made to a circle. Change the
   stroke width in the Ellipse options bar along the top.
4. Select the circle, then click Object > Expand Appearance, then
   Object > Ungroup several times until Ungroup is greyed out.
5. Then you can select each shape, and fill with your desired colour.

[image: Applying pattern brush to a circle]

If you have a shape you don't want to be distorted, you can make a Scatter Brush instead, and set the "Rotation relative to path" option, and adjust the spacing.

[image: Example of Scatter Brush]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the pieces are given - zero edits to them, only the placing: Move them to the cusps of a star:

[image]

Many pieces needed a little rotation, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a dashed stroke...

- Draw a circle
- Bump up the stroke weight to your desired width
- Check "Dashed Line" and set the dash and gap to your liking

You could even color it with a gradient on the stroke (or just expand appearance and set fills on the resulting shapes if setting up the gradient is too much work)...

[image]